# Manual metadata creation in BreezeJS

Tags: breeze, single-page-application

I have got some issues when I try to manually create the metadata of my data model. More specifically, I use the following command to create a string representation of the metadata which I then save to a local file.

```
var metadata = JObject.Parse(new EFContextProvider<HelixDtoContext>().Metadata());
```

There is some missing information, though, when i do it that way. The the following Dto

```
public class LayoutManagerState
{
    public string Widgets { get; set; }
}


public class AppState
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public ViewOptionsDialogState ViewOptionsDialogState { get; set; }
    public LayoutManagerState LayoutManagerState { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I would expect the metadata to include the LayoutManagerState complex property; However it doesn't do that.

```
"entityType": [
  {
    "name": "AppState",
    "key": {
      "propertyRef": {
        "name": "Id"
      }
    },
    "property": [
      {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "Edm.Int32",
        "nullable": "false",
        "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
      },
      {
        "name": "ViewOptionsDialogState",
        "type": "Edm.Self.ViewOptionsDialogState",
        "nullable": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
```

As you can see there is no property with the name `LayoutManagerState` in the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

**I cannot reproduce your failure.**

I took an existing app (one of the Todo samples) and dropped your two classes in like so:

```
public class LayoutManagerState {
    public string Widgets { get; set; }
}

public class AppState {
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public LayoutManagerState LayoutManagerState { get; set; }
}
```

I added the new `DbSet` to the `DbContext` like this:

```
public DbSet<AppState> AppStates { get; set; }
```

Then I looked at the metadata sent over the wire ... and it looks fine. Here are the three entity type definitions with your complex type at the top:

```
"complexType": {
  "name": "LayoutManagerState",
  "property": {
    "name": "Widgets",
    "type": "Edm.String",
    "maxLength": "4000",
    "fixedLength": "false",
    "unicode": "true"
  }
},
"entityType": [
  {
    "name": "AppState",
    "key": {
      "propertyRef": {
        "name": "Id"
      }
    },
    "property": [
      {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "Edm.Int32",
        "nullable": "false",
        "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
      },
      {
        "name": "LayoutManagerState",
        "type": "Edm.Self.LayoutManagerState",
        "nullable": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "TodoItem",
    "key": {
      "propertyRef": {
        "name": "Id"
      }
    },
    "property": [
      {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "Edm.Int32",
        "nullable": "false",
        "annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern": "Identity"
      },
      {
        "name": "Description",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "maxLength": "30",
        "fixedLength": "false",
        "unicode": "true",
        "nullable": "false"
      },
      {
        "name": "IsDone",
        "type": "Edm.Boolean",
        "nullable": "false"
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

Breeze imported it just fine too as evidenced by this test:

```
manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('LayoutManagerState'); // returns the complex type
```

What do you think accounts for the difference?

Comment: I located the issue; I've got the following projects in my solutions. 1) MyApp.Models 2) MyApp.Dtos 3) MyApp.UI 4) MyApp.MetadataGenerator. When the MVC app starts (MyAPP.UI) I call a method in the MyApp.MeatadataGenerator that returns the metadata string. When I do it this way, I don't get the full representation of my data model. However, if I run the MetadataGenerator as standalone Console  app, then the LayoutManagerState is included in the metadata.